# Is Bhagavad Gita with 745 verses available?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, translation-request, critical-edition

I read on a [website](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41682451) that the original Bhagavad Gita had 745 verses.

Is it true? If yes, is it available to read online?

Also, why were the 45 verses excised from the current version of Gita which only has 700 verses?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan : Is this the book which has 45 verse(https://archive.org/details/srimadbhagavadgi015443mbp) ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  That gives the verses in Sanskrit.  In my answer I give a link to Swami Lakshmanjoo's English translation and commentary on those verses.

Comment: This question is asking for an online version of Gita with 745 verses. Not a duplicate of the other.